# Is there a way to make a GET request without getting the body of the content?

Tags: html, http, protocols, network-protocols

I'm trying to do HEAD requests to follow 302 links, however this link: http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&usg=AFQjCNGrJk-F7Dmshmtze2yhifxRsv8sRg&url=http://www.mtv.com/news/articles/1647243/20100907/story.jhtml

is troublesome because a HEAD request returns a 200 OK and a GET request returns the expected 302 Status code.

So I'll need to do a GET request but I'd rather not have to pay for the extra bandwidth times that will come from getting the entire HTML document. Anyone know a hack to do a GET without getting the body returned?

UPDATE: took David's advice to do a Range header but they seem to still be ignoring it

```
GET /news/url?sa=t&fd=R&usg=AFQjCNGrJk-F7Dmshmtze2yhifxRsv8sRg&url=http://www.mtv.com/news/articles/1647243/20100907/story.jhtml HTTP/1.1
Range: bytes=0-10
x-ms-range: 0-600
Host: news.google.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)

HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: http://www.mtv.com/news/articles/1647243/20100907/story.jhtml
Content-Length: 258
Date: Wed, 08 Sep 2010 20:28:16 GMT
Expires: Wed, 08 Sep 2010 20:28:16 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=ef5f1bc768645c5e:TM=1283977696:LM=1283977696:S=5n26IrEDpcQTJIb1; expires=Fri, 07-Sep-2012 20:28:16 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.mtv.com/news/articles/1647243/20100907/story.jhtml">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: it looks like the web server (in this case Google news) is set to send back a 200 status code in the event of a HEAD request. this isn't the standard implementation, HEAD requests are supposed to return a 302 status code as well. Since it's a bug on their end I don't see that there is anything you can do about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. File a bug with the web server's owner.
2. Try using the [Range](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.35) header in your request.
3. If that doesn't work, can you just hang up the connection after you get the headers you want?

Comment: thanks David, didn't know about the Range header.. I'm now sending that but they're still ignoring it unless I didn't specific it correctly. I've updated my post with the results.

Comment: I guess it's just a cheapy web service. Try hanging up the socket? You could also just use the Location header regardless of the HTTP status.

Comment: on the head request they don't send back a location header, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In the specific example you cite, you could just pull it out of the original URL's "url" parameter.  But for a more generic approach, I'd stick to David M.'s suggestions

Comment: that only works for that one example, I'm dealing with millions of random urls currently